# Error when trying to create an Entity Framework Core database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a database via EF Core, however when I try to create, I get an error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation `TestResult.Evaluated` of type `User`. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the `[NotMapped]` attribute or by using `EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore` in `OnModelCreating`

My model classes:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    private string _secondName;
    private string _lastName;
    private Country _country;
    private Specialization _specialization;
    public virtual List<TestResult> Marks { get; set; }
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class TestResult
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User Evaluator { get; set; }
    public virtual User Evaluated { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class DataBase : DbContext
{
    public DataBase() : base()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Criterion> Criterions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Specialization> Specializations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            var connectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=marks;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use lazy load so that it regulates the relationships and data loading itself, but it doesn't work. Do I need to manually register all relationships in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Yes, you must manually create relations. Something like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<TestResult>().HasOne(x => x.Evaluator).WithMany(u => u.Marks).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);`

Comment: have you tried to had key properties: `public Guid EvaluatorId {get; set;}` and `public Guid EvaluatedId {get; set;}` to your TestResult entity class. If it works it will sound like magic to you, so remember that at middle term too much magic is never good. [relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)